# reactjs menu - conditional operator with nested data - setting the active state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am fairly new to reactjs - in this instance I am looping through json data - with a menu - sub menu nest.

so basically the menu json looks something like this

```
            {
                "title": "Dienstleistungen",
                "link": "/de/dienstleistungen",
                "children" : [
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "Beliebte Projekte",
                "link": "/de/beliebte-projekte",
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "title" : "Bundle1",
                        "link"  : "/de/beliebte-projekte/bundle1"
                    },
                    {
                        "title" : "Bundle2",
                        "link"  : "/de/beliebte-projekte/bundle2"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

now my issue is the logic for the active state -- currently from parent level this works fine -- so if the current page is /de/dienstleistungen -- the condition currently "item.link === activeLink" is true.

Now I will like to add more logic here to catch the children links if possible so something like this

item.link === activeLink || (item.children.inArray(activeLink))

//code

```
          {
            lang.menu.map(function (item, index) {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={(item.children.length > 0 ? 'has-dropdown' : '')}>
                  <Link to={item.link} className='headerbar-link-nav'>{item.title}</Link>
                  {
                    item.link === activeLink
                    ? <div className='main-nav active' /> : null
                  }
                  {
                    item.children.length > 0
                      ? <ul className='dropdown'>
                        {item.children.map(subPage => {
                          return (<li key={subPage.title}>
                            <Link to={subPage.link}>{subPage.title}</Link>
                          </li>
                          )
                        })}
                      </ul>
                    : null
                  }
                </li>
              )
            })
          }
```

I've just come up with this solution.

```
const inSubPages = function (obj, activeLink) {
      for (var k in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue
        if (obj[k].link === activeLink) {
          return true
        }
      }
      return false
    }
```

Comment: so basically if activeLink is "/de/beliebte-projekte/bundle1" -- then I want it to hunt in the children array - because the first part will fail as its not a parent link

Comment: I've come up with this --   const inSubPages = function (obj, activeLink) {
      for (var k in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue
        if (obj[k].link === activeLink) {
          return true
        }
      }
      return false
    }

Comment: So what happens now, like that condition becomes false correct, then ?

Comment: well -- item.link === activeLink || inSubPages(item.children, activeLink)

Comment: aah got it, so it should work seems legit to me

Comment: do you get any errors ?

Comment: it worked - but my co-dev may have chosen a different way "activeClassName='nav-active'"

Answer (score 0):

```
let isActive = item.link === activeLink;
item.children.forEach((child)=>{
    if(child.link === activeLink){
        isActive = true;
    }
})
```

Do this before the return statement inside the map function, and replace you ternary with just `isActive && <div className='main-nav active' />`

Comment: There is `Array.prototype.some` method that is there to check if any element matches a filter https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some?v=example